# Hide text in jqgrid header

Tags: text, jqgrid, header, hide, caption

I don't want any text to be displayed on my header.But, i need the header though.
**caption: " ",**
 removed the entire header. Help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correct your requirements you can use for example the following value of `caption` option:

```js
caption: "&nbsp;"
```

Comment: @lakshganga: By the way, I see that you don't use the right to vote (click on "up" arrow on the left part of question of answer). It's the most important right on stackoverflow. It gives hint for search engine that the answer/question is helpful and so other people will easy find it. You have right to vote 30 answers/questions **per day** which you find helpful (see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5213/147495)). So if you want help other visitors of stackoverflow please use you voting right active. The comment is not relative to my answer, but the common remark.

Comment: @lakshganga: I recommend you to examine at least answers on your old questions and vote up all which was helpful for you. In the future you can vote all interesting information which you find anywhere on the stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

`caption: "&nbsp;"`  - doesn't work in later versions. You should instead use:

```
label: "&nbsp;"
```